# IJulia is not connecting to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: julia, jupyter

Whenever I try to open up a Jupyter notebook via Anaconda, I do not have a "Julia" code option. I have tried using Pkg., uninstalling Julia and Anaconda but my Mac does not seem to be connecting the two. I have also tried to open a Jupyter notebook directly from the Julia Kernel and that still is not working! I'm not sure what the issue is or what I should do next, here is the error:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add "IJulia"
   Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
######################################################################## 100.0%
  Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you showed is not an error. It is saying that IJulia is already installed in your system.

You need to run the notebook method from `IJulia` package.
Do:

```
julia> Using IJulia

julia> notebook()
```

If you don't have juypter already installed it prompt asking if you want to install it simply press `y` and it will start it in your browser automatically.

Also if for any reason it didn't open it automatically you can open it yourself.
Type [`localhost:8888`](http://localhost:8888)(or you can click the link) in your browser url bar to open it.

Comment: I've tried this, but when it opens Jupyter it still only gives me the Python 3 option and not a Julia option when I try to open a new file.

Answer (score 0):

What you posted does not indicate an error, it merely says that IJulia is already installed in your default environment: no changes were needed to add it.

You next step should now be to run:

```
julia> using IJulia

julia> IJulia.notebook()
```

After this, a new notebook should open in your browser.

Comment: I've tried this, but when it opens Jupyter it still only gives me the Python 3 option and not a Julia option when I try to open a new file

Answer (score 0):

I ever had an issue like this also. To solve this you need to rebuild the `IJulia` by run like below:

```
Using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
Pkg.build("IJulia")
```